# OpenWrt on Raspberry Pi 4 does not support AC and 80MHz

Tags: raspberry-pi, openwrt, wifi-hotspot

So, i was gathering up info from the interwebs how to setup a Raspberry Pi 4 as an OpenWrt Router (Access Point, whatever you name it). And i'm happy to say that i was able to make WiFi work and to connect to it from an iPhone. Woohoo. This is so far what i came up with - https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQ2lDbAXV3b2Fzw9-LC7PRkirLQGqRH-iLm6cNcUz_b4lawJG_-57yWQKrYrbO8awSCcY_koax8os2e/pub (sorry for clunky formatting, i was typing it as i was testing). All cool, it works, but, there's a problem. it seems that it's not able to go to AC mode, and/or 80MHz bands. After Going `"htmode": "VHT80"` the network seems to disappear. `VHT20` and `VHT40` seems to work fine. Also, tried some other channel + `VHT80` combinations to no avail.

Maybe somebody had more luck with this, or is this a limitation of current firmware for the Pi?

I'm testing this on latest snapshot image (`openwrt-bcm27xx-bcm2711-rpi-4-ext4-factory`) on May 8th, 2020.

Thanks for any kind of input!

Edit (add more info):

```bsh
root@OpenWrt:~# ubus call system board
{
    "kernel": "5.4.39",
    "hostname": "OpenWrt",
    "model": "Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1",
    "board_name": "raspberrypi,4-model-b",
    "release": {
        "distribution": "OpenWrt",
        "version": "SNAPSHOT",
        "revision": "r13202-94f3449977",
        "target": "bcm27xx/bcm2711",
        "description": "OpenWrt SNAPSHOT r13202-94f3449977"
    }
}
```

```bsh
root@OpenWrt:~# wifi status
{
    "radio0": {
        "up": true,
        "pending": false,
        "autostart": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "retry_setup_failed": false,
        "config": {
            "hwmode": "11a",
            "path": "platform/soc/fe300000.mmcnr/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:0001/mmc1:0001:1",
            "legacy_rates": false,
            "country": "LT",
            "channel": "36",
            "htmode": "VHT40"
        },
        "interfaces": [
            {
                "section": "default_radio0",
                "ifname": "wlan0",
                "config": {
                    "mode": "ap",
                    "ssid": "OpenWrt",
                    "encryption": "psk2",
                    "key": "fosron123",
                    "network": [
                        "lan"
                    ],
                    "mode": "ap"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```bsh
root@OpenWrt:~# iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr dc:a6:32:28:3f:42
        ssid OpenWrt
        type AP
        channel 36 (5180 MHz), width: 40 MHz, center1: 5190 MHz
        txpower 31.00 dBm
```

```bsh
root@OpenWrt:~# iw list
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 10
    max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
    max # match sets: 16
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: 508
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x1022
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x1062
            HT20/HT40
            Static SM Power Save
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        VHT Capabilities (0x00001020):
            Max MPDU length: 3895
            Supported Channel Width: neither 160 nor 80+80
            short GI (80 MHz)
            SU Beamformee
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: not supported
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: not supported
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5170 MHz [34] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (13.0 dBm)
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 1
    Supported extended features:
        * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in station mode
        * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_1X ]: 4-way handshake with 802.1X in station mode
        * [ DFS_OFFLOAD ]: DFS offload
```